# Can go to admin page if logged in as user

Tags: php, session, authentication, admin

I'm working on a site where i want to have 2 pages. I have the login page, a welcomeadmin.php and a welcomeuser.php

If i log in with admin, i get redirected to the admin page and if i log in as a user i get redirected to the user page which is good.

**The problem** is that when i log in as **user** and get redirected to the user page, i can also acces the welcomeadmin.php by changing it in my URL.

**login.php:**

```
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to 
welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
if($_SESSION['functie'] == 'admin'){
    header("location: welcomeadmin.php");
}
else{
    header("location: welcomeuser.php");
}

exit;
}
```

**welcomeadmin.php**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){\
header("location: login.php");
exit;
}
```

**welcomeuser**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
header("location: login.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Use your `$_SESSION['functie']` inside welcomeadmin.php and welcomeuser.php

Comment: 2 things aren't clear for me and is if the `welcome page` is on 1 or 2 lines. Second, the `\`` in true){\. Is that actually part of your code?

Comment: executable, i keep getting errors whenever i do that

Comment: @Tim what error ?

Comment: My site just crashes

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: This is what i added to welcomeadmin. : if($_SESSION['functie'] == 'admin'){
        header("location: welcomeadmin.php");
    }
    else{
        header("location: welcomeuser.php");
    }

Comment: Maybe `$_SESSION['functie']` doesn't exist. Can you try `if(isset($_SESSION['functie']) and $_SESSION['functie'] == 'admin'){ header("location: welcomeadmin.php"); } else{ header("location: welcomeuser.php"); }`

Comment: It's still not working. this is the full session code that is on the start of my page       <?php
  
session_start();
 

if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){\
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}  
if(isset($_SESSION['functie']) and $_SESSION['functie'] == 'admin'){ header("location: welcomeadmin.php"); } else{ header("location: welcomeuser.php"); }

?>

Comment: What doesn't work ? Have error ?

Comment: It's fully working now. Thanks anyways @executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `welcomeadmin.php` file you don't check if the user that is trying to access the page is indeed an admin. You can add the check like in your `login.php` file with a simple if statement after your check if the user is logged in. Just add this Code Snippet after your first If in the `welcomeadmin.php` file.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["functie"]) || $_SESSION["functie"] != "admin") {
    header("location: welcomeuser.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: No problem, I'm always trying to help new developers. If my answer solved your problem please accept it so other people with the same or similar problems find the correct answer.